# Problema con rutas al ejecutar scripts de shell con PHP y al acceder a archivos en un path

Tags: php, linux, lighttpd

Tengo un servidor HTTP con lighttpd y uso php, he intentado ejecutar scripts sh o mismamente acceder a variables en una ruta concreta pero no funciona , creo que porque el directorio del archivo php se encuentra en `/var/www/html` y no puede acceder a ciertas rutas aun especificandolas.

Los comandos los ejecuto con `shell_exec` y respecto al archivo que quiero obtener y con el que trabajo es un archivo de configuracion en la ruta `/home/jorge/proyecto/`

Ejecutando comandos como `shell_exec('./test.sh')` ubicado en `/home/jorge/proyecto/` tampoco funciona.
No llega a ejecutar el comando , ni usando de path `./test.sh` ni `/home/jorge/proyecto/test.sh`

Las primeras lineas son una solucion que vi , pero parece que no funciona.

El problema es que leer lee bien el archivo (con el parse) pero no guarda correctamente en el path , el metodo esta bien, lo he comprobado , asi que el problema viene con los paths.

```
<?php

$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/home/jorge/proyecto/');
$new_path = getcwd();
echo $old_path; // el resultado es "/var/www/html"
echo $new_path; //el resultado es "/home/jorge/proyecto"

$path = "./config.ini";

//Vuelco en la variable $archivo las configuraciones que hay en el archivo especificado
//$archivo es un array asociativo
$archivo = parse_ini_file("./config.ini");

//Se guarda el contenido modificado, sobreescribiendo el fichero de configuracion
escribir_ini($archivo, $path);

$output = shell_exec('./test.sh')
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Generalmente funcionan mal con rutas relativas, en mi caso solo he podido usarlos con rutas completas. Has intentado eso ?

Comment: si , he utilizado rutas absolutas, en todo , ````/home/jorge/proyecto/test.sh``` pero el mismo problema , el caso es que es capaz de obtener el fichero pero no de crearlo,  y respecto a lo otro aun con ruta absoluta no da salida al "intentar" ejecutar un script en esa ruta

Comment: es linux , esa es la ruta absoluta, creo que te confundiste con Windows, en los tags puse linux :S, espero que me puedas ayudar un usando linux

Comment: Acá te dejo algo entonces de las rutas - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072580/php-shell-exec-directory Y además te dejo algo que pueda ayudar ademas https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php#118495

Comment: eso mismo he hecho , use chdir , despues de esa linea, el path es ```/home/jorge/proyecto``` y las restantes rutas uso ````config.ini``` o ```test.sh```, dado que ambos archivos serian encontrados dado que la ruta actual en ese momento seria la nueva , la que cambie

Comment: Que te dice el log?

Comment: nada ,creo que conseguir que se ejecutara , indicando el intreprete ```sh test.sh``` , pero aun sigo teniendo problemas al querer ejecutar comandos que necesitan root como ````systemctl restart mi_servicio.service```